# Making a circle around my Current Location in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, cllocation

Well, I know there isn't much documentation, examples or tutorials on Swift but I've been trying to read the documentation and it tells me this:

```
convenience init!(centerCoordinate coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius radius: CLLocationDistance)
```

I really have no clue what to do. I did this, but it keeps getting errors:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,
        longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

let rad = CLLocationDistance(1000)

convenience init!(coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance){
            self.init(radius: rad)
            self.init(coord: center)
    }
```

I would like to know how to implement this the right way.. I really tried for like 2-3 hours, reading about convenience inits and still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the documentation defines the convenience method as:

```
convenience init!(centerCoordinate coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius radius: CLLocationDistance)
```

But to use it you use:

```
MKCircle(centerCoordinate coord: CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius: CLLocationDistance)
```

So your code would be something like:

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
latitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude,
longitude: mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)

let rad = CLLocationDistance(1000)

MKCircle(centerCoordinate: center, radius: rad)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually did it, but I've seen to notice that this circle stays in the maps, and if the user moves, it creates another one, instead of moving it, making a whole bunch of circles in the map... is there any way to make one circle around the current location even if it moves?

Comment: Make your circle an optional instance variable. Each time you draw a circle, delete the previous one first. You could add some checks so that the user has to move a certain distance before a new circle is drawn but that's all app specific logic that you would want to decide.